# VBA Format number is not recognized

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code which looks for certain words in column R thern based on a specific word it will format the numbers in column Z.

The code i have is working for the formats for Aus and Aust but not for BEL. I believe its because the format for BEL is a number format and not a text format as the rest of them are.
I tried changing Format to NumberFormat but that errored out. Any idea how I can amend this.

```
Sub FormatNum()


Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Data")

With ws

lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "Z").End(xlUp).Row
For x = 2 To lastrow

If .Cells(x, "R") = "Aus" Then
.Cells(x, "Z") = Format(.Cells(x, "Z"), "000-00.000.000")

ElseIf .Cells(x, "R") = "Aust" Then
.Cells(x, "Z") = Format(.Cells(x, "Z"), "000-000000-000")

ElseIf .Cells(x, "R") = "Bel" Then
.Cells(x, "Z") = Format(.Cells(x, "Z"), "0000000000")

End If

Next

End With

MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: How many digits are in `.Cells(x, "Z")`? Probably everything is numeric. Is this assumption correct? Please show us an example which works in the previous two format ways and does not work in the third one.

Comment: When you say it isn't working for BEL, what does "isn't working" mean? Also, if you tried NumberFormat, show us how you tried to implement it -- you might not have got it quite right

Comment: If you have BEL in the cell and Bel in the code, the IF will not be evaulated.

Comment: By the way, you are not formatting the cell with this code, you are changing the value of the cells using a specific format. You maybe want to use cell.NumberFormat = "000-00.000.000"

Comment: Look at using `option compare text` or ucase/lcase to assist with @FrancescoGiossi 's comment

Comment: Hi, I've tried to add before and after screenshots. Not sure if it worked. Everything in column Z is numeric.     To change to NumberFormat i end up getting a compile error ElseIf .Cells(x, "R") = "Bel" Then
.Cells(x, "Z") = NumberFormat(.Cells(x, "Z"), "0000000000")

Comment: I think that the code does its job, like it is, but if `NumberFormat` is `General`, Excel converts the string in number. Just for testing reason try `.Cells(x, "Z").NumberFormat = "@": .Cells(x, "Z") = Format(.Cells(x, "Z"), "0000000000")`.

Comment: @FaneDuru This worked on my home computer and my work one. I would have never solved that so thanks. Now to rinse repeat for 30 other variations. It did change the number into text though, but it will probably work for what I need it for.

Comment: I would suggest you to firstly format the whole column as text and try the code like it is. It should work for all format versions, I think. You can do it programmatically, too.

Comment: that works for an answer for me.  It worked and kept it all as text. So eventually it was a simple solution. Convert to text then run the macro. I would have never considered that.

Comment: It is almost nothing to place an answer...  Try `ws.Range("Z:Z").NumberFormat = "@"` and use your existing code. In order to make it much faster, you should place the range in an array, iterate between the array elements, place the processed (formatted) string in a new array and drop its content at once. If interested, I can try an answer showing how to proceed...

Comment: I must leave my office now. In the mean time I posted an answer. Its code should be very fast. Please, test it and send some feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, try the next code. It uses two arrays and, working only in memory, should be very fast even for large ranges:

```
Sub FormatNum()
 Dim ws As Worksheet, arr, arrFin, lastRow As Long, x As Long

Set ws = ActiveSheet ' Sheets("Data")
 lastRow = ws.cells(ws.rows.count, "Z").End(xlUp).row
 arr = ws.Range("R2:R" & lastRow).Value
 ws.Range("Z:Z").NumberFormat = "@"
 arrFin = ws.Range("Z2:ZR" & lastRow).Value

 For x = 1 To UBound(arr)
    If arr(x, 1) = "Aus" Then
         arrFin(x, 1) = Format(arrFin(x, 1), "000-00.000.000")
    ElseIf arr(x, 1) = "Aust" Then
         arrFin(x, 1) = Format(arrFin(x, 1), "000-000000-000")
    ElseIf arr(x, 1) = "Bel" Then
        arrFin(x, 1) = Format(arrFin(x, 1), "0000000000")
    End If
 Next x
 ws.Range("Z2").Resize(UBound(arrFin), 1).Value = arrFin
 MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, this one also worked, Both my original and yours worked after the advice you gave me re changing it all to text then formatting that.

Answer (score 1):

According to useful comments, here is example how to set number format.
One useful link is [Excel Custom Format](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/07/07/custom-excel-number-format/)

```
Sub SetFormat()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Data")
    
    With ws
    
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "Z").End(xlUp).Row

        For x = 2 To lastrow
            Call SetCellFormat(.Cells(x, "R"), .Cells(x, "Z"))
        Next

    End With
    
    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub


Sub SetCellFormat(lang As Range, value As Range)
    Select Case LCase(lang.value)
        Case "aus"
            value.NumberFormat = "000\-00\.000\.000"
        Case "aust"
            value.NumberFormat = "000\-000000\-000"
        Case "bel"
            value.NumberFormat = "0000000000"
    End Select
    
End Sub
```

this code produces this result, but keeps data unchanged.

| R | S | T | U | V | W | X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AUS |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 001-23.456.789 |
| Aus |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 001-23.456.789 |
| aust |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 000-123456-789 |
| BEL |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0123456789 |

Comment: This worked on my home computer. However when I put it on my work computer it didn't. Very odd but a great way to solve this.